# .Net MVC - JQXGrid - Valid data displaying as Blank Rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, jqxgrid

My JQXGrid is being loaded properly with JSON.  I have comfirmed that at each step the data is both valid and correct.  I have a simple query that loads all records from a SQL db and places them in the JQXGrid.  The db has only 1 element (for testing purposes).

[image: JQXGrid]

You can see at the paginator that the grid has the proper number (1) of elements.  I have highlighted the only row that exists in the table.  In each column, the data appears as blank (again, I have confirmed the data is correct).  I have also confirmed that the datafields are correct.

JQXGrid:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

$("#txtSearch").bind("keypress", {}, keypressInBox);

function keypressInBox(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 13) { //Enter keycode
        e.preventDefault();

        loadGrid();
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {

    loadGrid();

});

function loadGrid() {
    var search = $("#txtSearch").val();

    var url = "/AIR/GetAIRs/?search=" + search;

    // prepare the data
    var source =
    {
        datatype: "json",
        datafields: [

             { text:  'EditLink', type: 'string'},
            { text: 'emissionUnit', type: 'string' },
            { text:  'emissionDesc', type: 'string' },
            { text:  'Process', type: 'string' },
            { text:  'ProcessDescription', type: 'string' },
            { text:  'Buildings', type: 'string' },
            { text: 'LastUpdateDate', type: 'date' },

            { text: 'DeleteLink', type: 'string' }
],
        url: url,
        pager: function (pagenum, pagesize, oldpagenum) {
            // callback called when a page or page size is changed.
        }
    };

    var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
    $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
    {
        width: '100%',
        source: dataAdapter,
        selectionmode: 'multiplerowsextended',
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        filterable: true,
        filtermode: 'excel',
        autoheight: true,
        columnsheight: 45,
        columnsresize: true,
        autorowheight: true,
        pagerheight: 60,

        columns: [
             { text: "", datafield: "EditLink", width: 80 },
            { text: "Emission Unit", datafield: "emissionUnit", width: 125 },
            { text: "Emission Description", datafield: "emissionDesc", width: 200 },
            { text: "Process", datafield: "Process", width: 125 },
            { text: "Process Description", datafield: "ProcessDescription", width: 200 },
            { text: "Buildings", datafield: "Buildings", width: 150 },
            { text: "Last Update Date", datafield: "LastUpdateDate", cellsformat: 'd', width: 150 },

            { text: "", datafield: "DeleteLink", width: 80 }

        ]
    });
};
```

Model:

```
    public class EmissionUnitMatrixModel
{
    [Key]
    [DisplayName("EmissionUnitMatrixID")]
    public int EmissionUnitMatrixID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("EmissionUnitLookupID")]
    public int? EmissionUnitLookupID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("ProcessID")]
    public int? ProcessID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("LastUpdateDate")]
    public DateTime? LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("LastUpdateBy")]
    public string LastUpdateBy { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("CreatedDate")]
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("CreatedBy")]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Active")]
    public bool? Active { get; set; }
    public string ActiveText { get; set; }
    public string EditLink { get; set; }
    public string DeleteLink { get; set; }
    public string ProcessDescription { get; set; }
    public string Process { get; set; }
    public string emissionUnit { get; set; }
    public string Buildings { get; set; }
    public string emissionDesc { get; set; }

}
```

Controller:

```
        public JsonResult GetAIRs(string search)
    {
        var surveys = dashboardService.GetAIRList();
        var json = Json(surveys, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return json;
    }
```

DAL:

```
        public List<EmissionUnitMatrixModel> GetAIRList()
    {


        var query = emuserivce.GetAll();



        return query.ToList();
    }
```

TL;DR

I confirmed that the JSON being sent to my JQXGrid was both valid and correct.  The JSON contains 1 row of data.  The table renders with the correct # of rows, yet the entire row is blank.  Please advice with suggestions or thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a problem in your javascript source part. According to their [article](http://www.jqwidgets.com/binding-jquery-grid-to-json-data/) on binding json data to grid, each member of `datafields` should have `name` and optional `type`. But in your implementation you have `text` in place of `name`.

So it should be like:

```
// prepare the data
    var source =
    {
        datatype: "json",
        datafields: [    
            { name: 'EditLink', type: 'string'},
            { name: 'emissionUnit', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'emissionDesc', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'Process', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'ProcessDescription', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'Buildings', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'LastUpdateDate', type: 'date' },    
            { name: 'DeleteLink', type: 'string' }
        ],
        url: url,
        pager: function (pagenum, pagesize, oldpagenum) {
            // callback called when a page or page size is changed.
        }
    };
```

Comment: Great attention to Detail!